AttributeError: module 'streamlit' has no attribute 'connection'
    Traceback:
    File     "/usr/lib/python_udf/3dddbf5d6aecbf84663dccc617833ebd4259a340dc5b8c7400c09b95b823aee0/lib/python3    .8/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 565, in _run_script
        exec(code, module.__dict__)
    File "/tmp/appRoot/streamlit_app.py", line 23, in <module>
        cnx=st.connection("snowflake")

    # Import python packages
    import streamlit as st
    #from snowflake.snowpark.context import get_active_session
    from snowflake.snowpark.functions import col

    # Write directly to the app
    st.title("Customize Your Smoothie :cup_with_straw:")
    st.write(
        """Choose the fruits you want in your custom Smoothie!
        """
    )
    name_on_order = st.text_input("Name on Smoothie:")
    st.write("The name on your Smoothie will be:", name_on_order)

    cnx=st.connection("snowflake")
    session=cnx.session()
    my_dataframe = session.table("smoothies.public.fruit_options").select(col('FRUIT_NAME'))

    ingredients_list=st.multiselect(
        'Choose up to 5 ingredients:',
        my_dataframe,
        max_selections=5
    )
    if ingredients_list:
        ingredients_string=''

        for fruit_chosen in ingredients_list:
            ingredients_string += fruit_chosen + ' '
 
        my_insert_stmt = """ insert into smoothies.public.orders(ingredients,name_on_order)
                    values ('""" + ingredients_string + """','"""+name_on_order+"""')"""
    
        time_to_insert=st.button('Submit Order')

        if time_to_insert:
            session.sql(my_insert_stmt).collect()
            st.success('Your Smoothie is ordered!', icon="✅")

I'm new to snowflake and trying to executing above code in snowflake (SiS) and also in SNiS but getting above error.
I tried with st.experimental_connection() and downgrading the streamlit version (current is 1.31.1) but didn't work.
Please shade some light
Thanks.

Are you working with Streamlit in Snowflake?  If so, the connection is something like session = get_active_session() since it's already running inside of Snowflake.
